# Boxee web streaming juddering

Tags: video-streaming, boxee

I have a win7 boxee box running 2.6Ghz P4 and 1gb RAM, and 512Mb GFX card outputting to HDMI.

Boxee runs 1080, 720 and SD local content extremely well (local content is actually a NAS).

The only problem I am having is that streaming content from the web is juddering pretty badly so much so as to make it unwatchable.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't just network latency?

Comment: positive, running streams through web/sopcast work fine.